# fetch all nodes and relationships of a particular type of label

Tags: neo4j, recursive-query

I am trying to fetch all the connected  nodes and relationships of a particular label type.
I am using this query but I doesn't produce connected nodes, instead it gives the starting node and its edges but not the consecutive nodes.

How do i get all the nodes and edges?

The query I have already tried are:

```
MATCH p=(:Document)-[*]-(others) Return nodes(p),relationships(p);

START n=node(:Document) MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m;
```

Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is via the path [expander procs from APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths):

```
MATCH (d:Document)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(d, {}) YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN d, nodes, relationships
```